# jQuery incorrectly counting elements

Tags: jquery, checkbox

This much I have already cobbled together (thanks to Stack Overflowers):

I have a series of product modules, each of which contains a product name and a checkbox. Checking a checkbox adds the corresponding product name to a list elsewhere on the page, un-checking a checkbox removes the coresponding product name from the list. When the user submits the 'Compare' button, I need jQuery to check the number of selections, confirming a minimum of two and an arbitrary maximum.

My problem: the following jQuery is apparently failing to account for items which have been removed (by unchecking). For example, if I check a checkbox, then uncheck it - and it does get unchecked, and it does get removed from the list - and then re-check it, jQuery reports that there are 2 items to be compared.

```
<div class="product-module">
<div class="product-pic">
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
        <label for="compare1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="compare" id="compare1" />
            Compare
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-info">
    <p><a href="#" title="#"><span class="product-name">Product Name here</span></a></p>    
</div>
</div>


<div class="compare">
<ul>
</ul>
<p class="compare-button"><button type="submit">Compare</button></p>
<p class="clear-selections"><a class="button" id="clear-selections" href="#">Clear Selections</a></p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
// clear all checkboxes on load
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
});


    $(function(){
    $('.column-main input[type="checkbox"]').click(function()    {
        var title = $(this).closest('.product-module').find('.product-name').html();

        // if user checks the checkbox, add the item to the ul
        if    ($(this).attr('checked'))    {
        var html = '<li><a href="'+title+'">' + title + '</a></li>';
        $('.compare ul').append(html);

        // if user un-checks the checkbox, remove the item from the ul
        }    else if ($(this).attr('checked', false))    {
        $('li a[href="' + title + '"]').remove();
        }
    })
})


$(function(){
    $('.clear-selections').click(function(){
        $('.compare ul').empty();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
    })
});

    $(function(){
    $('.compare button').click(function(){
        minRequests = 2;
        maxRequests = 3;
        requested = $('.compare ul li').size();    // go figure: why not .length()?

        if(requested < 2)    {
        alert ('Compare ' + requested + ' products?');

        } else if((requested >= 2) && (requested <= 5 ))    {
        alert ('There are ' + requested + ' products to compare');

        } else {
        alert (requested + ' is too many');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$('li a[href$="' + title + '"]').remove();
```

You're removing the 'a' tag from inside the 'li', but leaving the 'li' - which is what you count later.

Try:

```
$('li a[href$="' + title + '"]').parent().remove();
```

Comment: Good eye.  I've been staring at this for 10 minutes now :(

Comment: sje397: Thank you so much! I've been hacking at it for days!

Comment: ACK! any idea why un-checking isn't removing in IE7? :(

Comment: @shecky - sorry, i don't have a working IE anywhere, and know little about its 'quirks'